# update() object RTDB Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Why, when I try to update the `titulo` field of an Realtime Database object in firebase, does it generate another field? What is the correct way to update? I was looking at the documentation: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/objects.md and if I work the example that they show there but that is with a list. In this case I am working with the object on a different page. Any ideas?

[image]

editar.component.html

```
<input type="text" #newtitulo [value]="titulo"/>
<button (click)="updateProyecto(key, newtitulo.value)">Update</button>
```

editar.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList, AngularFireObject } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { FirebaseService } from '../../../servicios/firebase.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-editar-proyecto',
  templateUrl: './editar-proyecto.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./editar-proyecto.component.scss']
})
export class EditarProyectoComponent implements OnInit {


  proyectosRef: AngularFireObject<any>;
  proyecto: Observable<any[]>;
  id;
  titulo;
  destacado;
  descripcion;


  constructor(private fs: FirebaseService, private activateRoute: ActivatedRoute, private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.proyectosRef = db.object('/proyectos');
    this.proyecto = this.proyectosRef.valueChanges();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.activateRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.fs.getProyectoDetalles(this.id).valueChanges().forEach(proyecto => {
      this.titulo = proyecto.titulo;
      this.destacado = proyecto.destacado;
      this.descripcion = proyecto.descripcion;
    });
  }

  updateProyecto(key: string, newTitulo: string) {
    this.proyectosRef.update({ titulo: newTitulo });
  }

}
```

Comment: Actually you are updating child node of root node which is the timestamp.  First you have to get the auto generated id of the child node under which the whole child is saved. And use that key to get the reference to the child to be updated. Because the child node is saved under the timestamp id not main root reference node.

Answer (score 0):

Your path in update function is not correct.

it should be `this.proyectosRef.child(key).update({ titulo: newTitulo });`

i believe key is the uid to edit.

Comment: I tried but it tells me that `child` does not exist in the `AngularFireObject<any>` type. If you can, take a look at the Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sftzts?embed=1&file=app/portafolio-detalles/portafolio-detalles.component.html

Comment: Then you not getting correct key. Use snapshotChanges instead of valueChanges

Answer (score 0):

First get the firebase child timestamp id for child you wants to update by comparing it with the value key you wants to update. And then use that id in child to reference to that particular child node.

```
this.proyectosRef.orderByChild(proyecto.titulo).once("value", function(snapshot) {
  this.proyectosRef.child(snapshot.key).update({  titulo: newTitulo }, () =>{
                          console.log("record updated")
                        })
});
```

You have to find the time-stamp autogenerated key of that particular node you wants to update by the name of child node using `orderByChild` function. Please consider following link to get more idea https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/orderbychild.html

Comment: I get the following error: `property 'orderByChild' does not exist in type AngularFireObject <any>`. If you can, take a look at the Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sftzts?embed=1&file=app/portafolio-detalles/portafolio-detalles.component.html

Comment: there should be a method to get child by name of the child node key. Then you can get the reference to auto-generated timestamp. I have given you the firebase with node js. It is stated in firebase document. I have edited the answer just check the link in it.